# Animating constraints is breaking other constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I have the following tableview at the bottom of my view

[image]

It has a height constraint (priority 250) and a constraint to the bottom of the view (priority 1000). The height constraint points to a `IBOutlet in my view controller.

I want to change the height of the table view from 44.0f to 7*44.0f, so what I am doing is this;

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.categoriesShown) {
        [self hideCategories];
    } else {
        [self showCategories];
    }

    self.categoriesShown = !self.categoriesShown;
}

- (void)showCategories
{
    self.categoriesHeightConstraint.constant = self.categories.count * 44.0f;
}

- (void)hideCategories
{
    self.categoriesHeightConstraint.constant = 44.0f;
}
```

It works fine. But when I'm trying to animating all this with the following code:

```
- (void)showCategories
{
    [self.categoryTableView layoutIfNeeded];

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.categoryTableView duration:0.3f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

        self.categoriesHeightConstraint.constant = self.categories.count * 44.0f;
        [self.categoryTableView layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:nil];
}

- (void)hideCategories
{
    [self.categoryTableView layoutIfNeeded];

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.categoryTableView duration:0.3f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

        self.categoriesHeightConstraint.constant = 44.0f;
        [self.categoryTableView layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:nil];
}
```

Then the constraints between the tableview and the bottom of the view is somehow broken and this is what I get when I show and then hide the tableview

[image]

**Does anyone know why, the constraint is broken but only when I try to animate the changes?**

Update: UIButton Constraints

Both buttons have width and height constraints as well a a constraint to the bottom of the view. The button on the left has a leading constraint to the view. The one of the right has a trailing constraint to the view. The also both have a horizontal spacing constraint to the table view as mentioned above.

[image]

Comment: I tested your layout without the 2 buttons and with fixing the sides of the tableview to the superview and it worked fine. Something is going on with these 2 buttons. Can you show all your constraints?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I don't see anything wrong with these constraints. I added a screenshot. Hope it can help.

Comment: What are the 2 vertical lines from the buttons up?

Comment: They're the Leading and Trailing Constraints between the buttons and the view

Comment: I even removed the map view that was behind and the buttons to see if they had something to do with the issue but I get the same problem.

Comment: Try to use View Debugging (Debug / View Debugging / Capture View Hierarchy) when views are in invalid state. Then go to the Utilities window and press [Show the Size Inspector](http://pbrd.co/1LMfwGK). Use it to check what constrains affected your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in this method call:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.categoryTableView duration:0.3f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

        self.categoriesHeightConstraint.constant = 44.0f;
        [self.categoryTableView layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:nil];
```

This should do what you're looking for:

```
self.categoriesHeightConstraint.constant = 44.0f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    //This is assuming the method is called from a view controller.
    //You need to call layoutIfNeeded on the superview of what you're animating
}];
```

Also, Apple documentation says it's good form to make an extra `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` call before you change the constraint so that any incomplete constraint changes and be updated. I'll leave that up to you though.

Comment: It gives exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I got the functionality you're looking for:

I gave the table view a height constraint that matched the top of the buttons, but it could be anything.

Then I get the calculated height the table should be and set it:

```
tableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[tableArray addObject:@"Row 1"];
[tableArray addObject:@"Row 2"];
etc.......


double newHeight = ([tableArray count] * 44);
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(basicTable.frame.origin.x, basicTable.frame.origin.y, basicTable.frame.size.width, newHeight);
[basicTable setFrame:newFrame];
```

And then for your animation I used [UIView animateWithDuration] as shown:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

    tableHgtConst.constant = newHeight;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {


}];
```

I just left the bottom constraint alone, then changing the height constraint to match the height forces the table up instead of down.

Screens:
Simulator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7MBr.png

Code File: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGOkq.png

Comment: complete XCode project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w48k53qqv1vvkfb/AADuviQ99iYEGC5fZd0pPCxKa?dl=0